# two questions about character tables

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

I have learnt about group theory before I learnt MO theory, so I have a mathematical understanding of those orthogonality theorems and character tables.

I will use the character table of $D_{4h}$ to ask my questions:
[image]

1. **About basis functions**

   In the character table, we can see that the basis functions of $A_{1u}$ are not listed. Does it mean that any function can be a basis function of the corresponding invariant subspace?

   For $E_{u}$, we know that the dimension of the invariant subspace is two, then does it mean that any pair of functions listed can be regarded as a set of basis functions?
2. **About labels of irreducible representations**

   I learnt that those labels for irreducible representations are called Mulliken symmetry labels. But I don't understand what are the symmetries that we check? For instance, $A_{1g}$, is that we check the symmetries of $x^2 + y^2$ or $z^2$ (which are basis functions) that we get such a label?

Comment: For 1, yes, though it's really a matrix in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. For 2, the notation for Mulliken symbols is well documented, e.g., http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MullikenSymbols.html

Comment: @Zhe thank you for the answers! But for 1, I just can't build the intuition of any function can serve as a basis function, are there some materials that can help me make sense of this? For 2, I read the explanation,  but I think it doesn't answer my question, whose symmetry that we are checking? basis functions?

Comment: I'm confused by these questions. We're trying to describe matrices and their symmetries under the group operations. The functions just correspond to matrices that have the correct symmetry under the operations of the group.

As an aside, why can't functions serve as a basis? For well defined functions, you can Taylor expand the function, and $x^{n}$ for non-negative $n$ is your basis set. For periodic functions, you can expand into a Fourier series.

Comment: @Zhe ... I just realized that the choice of basis is arbitrary, thank you! But there's a quick question, if a function can be represented by the linear combination of all the basis functions of a point group, then are there some properties that the function should satisfy?

Comment: Yes, the functions should have the same symmetries as the matrices in the irreducible representation.

Comment: @Zhe which means the functions have to be invariant under all the symmetry operations of the group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67584/discussion-between-kangyu-zhang-and-zhe).